# Select2: does not work once loaded through onclick event in vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, jquery-select2

We implemented the select2 on our select options in our project. In our project, we have item section(Inventory, Quantity and Unit) and in the bottom part there's a button "Add Item".

When I clicked the "Add Item", it will add new row in my item section. But the added row,my inventory doesn't have select2

**EXAMPLE:**

// 
// As you can see here, this is the default when the user clicked the "Add" button

[image]

// When the user clicked the "Add Item"

[image]

As you can see, the select2 of my 2nd row in item didn't work but when I try again to add a new item. It will work.

[image]

Question: Why I have to add another row before my previous row in item to have a select2?

**ADD vue**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @click="addItem"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Item</button>
```

**Event**

```
function getAssetLimit(){
var table = 'assets'
$('select.asset').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select Asset',
    allowClear: true,
    ajax: {
        url: '/select2/getAssetFilterLimit',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function(params) {
            return {
                term: params.term || '',
                page: params.page || 1,
                table: params.table || table
            }
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
}
// export default

methods: {

    addItem(e) {
        e.preventDefault();


            getAssetLimit();
        // if (this.asset === 'undefined' || this.asset === '') {
            this.inputs.push({
                asset_id: '',
                unit: '',
                description: '',
            });

    },
```

**Clicked the Add Item**

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="(input, i) in inputs" :key="i">
      <td class="sticky">
          <select class="form-control-input form-control asset" name="item_asset[]" :data-counter="i+1">
              <option></option>
          </select>
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="number" name="item_quantity[]" class="form-control form-control-input item-quantity" step="0.0001" required>
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="text" name="item_unit[]" class="form-control form-control-input item-unit" readonly="readonly" :data-counter="i+1">
      </td>
<!--           <td v-if="asset[2]">
          <textarea name="item_specification[]" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" :data-counter="i">{{ asset[2] | striphtml }}</textarea>
      </td> -->
      <!-- <td v-else>  -->
      <td> 
          <textarea name="item_description[]" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" :data-counter="i+1"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: whenever I see jQuery being used in vue, I think ... no ... do you get any output in the developer tools console?

Comment: You want to know if there's an error after I clicked the Add Item? There's no error when I clicked the Add Item.

Comment: ok, can you add some console.logging to see what is happening maybe? just aq suggestion